# Adding multiple rows to a table with a procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to run a stored procedure to add 3 consecutive books to a table...

Here is my query...

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.AddCards @cnt int   
AS 
BEGIN    
   while(@cnt < 810010010513) 
   begin 
      insert into prepaidbooks(sbarcode, sdescription, lServiceId, iQty, dblWashValue, dblBookPrice, lLocationId, lBookTypeId)  
      values(@cnt, 'Dealer Car Wash', 43, 1, 9, 0, 1, 7)  

      set @cnt = @cnt + 1  
    END 
END
```

It's not working correctly... I get a box comes up asking me to define `@CNT` with  in the value box. I change it to 810010010511 and I get

> Cannot be converted

if I leave it  I get:

> Procedure or Function 'AddCards' expects parameter '@cnt', which was
>   not supplied.
>
> No rows affected.
>   (0 row(s) returned)
>   @RETURN_VALUE =  Finished running [dbo].[AddCards].

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! If you post error messages, **please** use the blockquotes ( ` " ` ) to properly format the error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`810010010511` is **too large** for an `int` - either use `BIGINT` or use a smaller number (`int` goes up to `2147483648`)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.AddCards
      @cnt BIGINT
AS 
BEGIN    
   WHILE (@cnt < 810010010513) 
   BEGIN 
      INSERT INTO dbo.prepaidbooks(sbarcode, sdescription, lServiceId, iQty, dblWashValue, dblBookPrice, lLocationId, lBookTypeId)  
      VALUES (@cnt, 'Dealer Car Wash', 43, 1, 9, 0, 1, 7)  

      SET @cnt = @cnt + 1  
    END 
END
```

Now you should be able to execute this like so:

```
EXECUTE dbo.AddCards @cnt = 810010010511
```

and get your values in the table.

As a side note: "hard-coding" such a value like `WHILE (@cnt < 810010010513)` into a stored procedure is a really bad idea. You will not be able to re-use that stored procedure for any other cases.... **at least** you should pass in the "upper limit" for your `@cnt` as a second parameter to the stored procedure - something like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.AddCards
      @cnt BIGINT, @max BIGINT
AS 
BEGIN    
   WHILE (@cnt < @max) 
   BEGIN 
      INSERT INTO dbo.prepaidbooks(sbarcode, sdescription, lServiceId, iQty, dblWashValue, dblBookPrice, lLocationId, lBookTypeId)  
      VALUES (@cnt, 'Dealer Car Wash', 43, 1, 9, 0, 1, 7)  

      SET @cnt = @cnt + 1  
    END 
END
```

and then execute your stored procedure something like this:

```
EXECUTE dbo.AddCards @cnt = 810010010511, @max = 810010010513
```

Comment: Yea, and change < to <= so it gets up to your max.  Otherwise it stops 1 below.

Answer (score 0):

I have a different proposal instead of a loop. This will handle about 2000 consecutive books if you need more you can add a cross join. Borrowing the updated signature from @marc_s (and assuming that `< 810010010513` was really supposed to be `<=`, since you said you wanted 3 books, not 2):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.AddCards
  @cnt BIGINT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --INSERT dbo.prepaidbooks
    --(
    --   sbarcode, sdescription, lServiceId, iQty, 
    --   dblWashValue, dblBookPrice, lLocationId, lBookTypeId
    --)  
    SELECT rn, 'Dealer Car Wash' --, 43, 1, 9, 0, 1, 7
    FROM 
    (
      SELECT TOP (CONVERT(INT, 810010010513 - (@cnt)) + 1) rn = 
        810010010513 - (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) - 1)
      FROM sys.all_objects
      ORDER BY [object_id]
    ) AS y
    ORDER BY rn;
END
GO

EXEC dbo.AddCards 810010010511;
```

Results:

```
810010010511  Dealer Car Wash
810010010512  Dealer Car Wash
810010010513  Dealer Car Wash
```

When you're happy with the output, uncomment the `INSERT` portion (I left that out so that you can test the output) and the remainder of the `SELECT` list (I only left them out for brevity).

Also I'd suggest you rename the parameter - it's not very intuitive. Strictly, you're not passing a count; what you're really passing is some kind of marker for where you want the count to start.